# How to add a label for arcgis 3D map, javascript 4.0

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am new to ArcGIS map development in javascript, I am trying to add a labelClass for 3D graphic layer.
Can anyone help me how to add a label for 3D map using javascript 4.0

Comment: The question is not clear.
The graphic layers do not support labelingInfo method.
The featurelayer support labelingInfo method.
What do you need?

Comment: I wanted to add label for Graphic to graphicLayer, I don't have a feature layer, thank you for your reply, I understood that the graphic layers do not support labeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.
To add label to a graphic you must use TextSymbol3DLayer and add, for each graphic, another graphic with TextSymbol3DLayer.
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>3D Graphics - 4.0</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/"></script>

  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/SceneView",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",

        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/geometry/Point",
        "esri/geometry/Polyline",
        "esri/geometry/Polygon",

        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/TextSymbol",

        "esri/symbols/TextSymbol3DLayer",

        "dojo/domReady!"
      ],
      function(
        Map, SceneView, GraphicsLayer,
        Graphic, Point, Polyline, Polygon,
        SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, TextSymbol,
        TextSymbol3DLayer
      ) {

        var map = new Map({
          basemap: "hybrid"
        });

        var view = new SceneView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,

          camera: { // autocasts as new Camera()
            position: { // autocasts as new Point()
              x: -0.17746710975334712,
              y: 51.44543992422466,
              z: 1266.7049653716385
            },
            heading: 0.34445102566290225,
            tilt: 82.95536300536367
          }
        });

        /*********************
         * Add graphics layer
         *********************/

        var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

        map.add(graphicsLayer);

        /*************************
         * Add a 3D point graphic
         *************************/

        // London
        var point = new Point({
            x: -0.178,
            y: 51.48791,
            z: 1010
          }),

          markerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
            color: [226, 119, 40],

            outline: { // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
              color: [255, 255, 255],
              width: 2
            }
          });

        var attrs = {};
        attrs["COUNTY"] = "Pippo";
        var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: point,
          symbol: markerSymbol
        });

        graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);

        var textSymbol = new TextSymbol({
          color: "white",
          haloColor: "black",
          haloSize: "1px",
          text: "You are here",
          xoffset: 3,
          yoffset: 3,
          font: {  // autocast as esri/symbols/Font
            size: 12,
            family: "sans-serif",
            weight: "bolder"
          }
        });

        var pointGraphic2 = new Graphic({
          geometry: point,
          symbol: textSymbol
        });
        graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic2);
        /****************************
         * Add a 3D polyline graphic
         ****************************/

        var polyline = new Polyline([
            [-0.178, 51.48791, 0],
            [-0.178, 51.48791, 1000]
          ]),

          lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol({
            color: [226, 119, 40],
            width: 4
          });

        var polylineGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: polyline,
          symbol: lineSymbol
        });

        graphicsLayer.add(polylineGraphic);

        /***************************
         * Add a 3D polygon graphic
         ***************************/

        var polygon = new Polygon([
            [-0.184, 51.48391, 400],
            [-0.184, 51.49091, 500],
            [-0.172, 51.49091, 500],
            [-0.172, 51.48391, 400],
            [-0.184, 51.48391, 400]
          ]),

          fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol({
            color: [227, 139, 79, 0.8],
            outline: { // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
              color: [255, 255, 255],
              width: 1
            }
          });

        var polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: polygon,
          symbol: fillSymbol
        });

        graphicsLayer.add(polygonGraphic);

      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```